# Where should I host personal websites?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I'm making a simple website for a family friend. I'm still new to the whole coding world, so I'm still trying to figure basic stuff out.

In terms of hosting the site, I've found quite a few hosting services with different options. For example, I could get a BlueHost premium account and then be able to host all of my future websites.

My main question, from a business perspective, is how do companies or freelance front-end developers host sites? Then, on top of that question, should I do the same with this personal site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you currently are looking only for personal use, with very less traffic then the best that I can think of is **HEROKU** (also free tier is available).

For professional use I would recommend still recommend **Heroku** for a very troublesome free hosting, but if you need professional type control, I would like to recommend **GCP/AWS** (both of them equally).
Other Hosting to be considered **Netlify**.